# gstreamer linking error (when using gstglfilter)

Tags: cmake, linker, gstreamer, linker-errors, gstreamer-1.0

When I build my gstreamer project using CMake I use the following CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
include(FetchContent)

project(someproject)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

pkg_check_modules(GST REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0>=1.4
        gstreamer-sdp-1.0>=1.4
        gstreamer-video-1.0>=1.4
        gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0>=1.4
        gstreamer-app-1.0>=1.4
        gstreamer-gl-1.0>=1.4)

#some other calls to find_package

add_library(someproject "")

#add source directories

target_include_directories(GUI_lib PUBLIC include "${OTHER_FIND_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
        "${GST_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

target_link_libraries(someproject PUBLIC "${OTHER_FIND_PACKAGE_LIBS}" "${GST_LIBRARIES}"  -lGL -lepoxy)
```

This results in the following error:

```sh
in function `drawCallback(_GstElement*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*)':
  undefined reference to `gst_gl_filter_get_type'
  undefined reference to `gst_gl_filter_draw_fullscreen_quad'
```

I have searched my gstreamer install and verified that there exists a shared library that defines these symbols using the following snippet (asterisks for emphasis):

```sh
% readelf -s --wide /usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopengl.so | rg gl_filter           
    121: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND gst_gl_filter_render_to_target_with_shader
*   242: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND gst_gl_filter_draw_fullscreen_quad
    305: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND gst_gl_filter_add_rgba_pad_templates
    421: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND gst_gl_filter_render_to_target
*   447: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND gst_gl_filter_get_type
    470: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND gst_gl_filter_filter_texture
```

So, I added the following to my CMake file:

```
add_library(gstopenglextras SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(gstopenglextras PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopengl.so")
```

I also changed the `target_link_libraries` call to:

```
target_link_libraries(someproject PUBLIC "${OTHER_FIND_PACKAGE_LIBS}" gstopenglextras "${GST_LIBRARIES}" -lGL -lepoxy)
```

Now I get the following linker error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: undefined reference to symbol 'gst_gl_filter_get_type'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libgstgl-1.0.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
```

I've read some stuff on circular dependencies and I've tried adding `"${GST_LIBRARIES}"` before `gstopenglextras`. However, this does not change the error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
target_link_libraries(
  someproject
  PUBLIC
    "${OTHER_FIND_PACKAGE_LIBS}"
    gstopenglextras
    "${GST_LIBRARIES}"
    -lGL
    -lepoxy
    gstgl-1.0
    glib-2.0
    gmodule-2.0
)
```

is the call you need to fix this issue.